# Constants not accessible in called class

Tags: php, routes, constants

I am currently having some notices about my constants, that's not set. I my routing class, I do something like this:

```
define('_CALLED_MODULE',$v->match_array['module']);
define('_CALLED_CONTROLLER',$v->match_array['controller']);
define('_CALLED_METHOD',$v->match_array['method']);

# Load the routed class.
if( class_exists($controllerName, true) && method_exists($controllerName, $methodName) )
{
    $this->route_params = $v->match_array['params'];

    $dispatch = new $controllerName();
    return call_user_func_array(array($dispatch, $methodName), $v->match_array['params']);
} else {
    $this->Error = new \Framework\Error\Error;
    return $this->Error->bootstrap('404');
}
```

My problem is, that in the class, I call, I can't get to use my constants, that is defined. I have always thought of constants as being in a global scope - is that wrong?

This means that when I've defined them, I could use them in any called class/function, but that doesn't seem to be right, since I get the following Notices:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant _CALLED_MODULE - assumed '_CALLED_MODULE'
```

Am I using the constants wrong? How should I pass global data instead?

### EXPLANATION OF LOGIC

- My router has an array of routes which is connected to the URL.
- The router loops through this array
- When a match is found, the router defines the module, controller and method
- The checks if the class with the namespace and name is existing
- The class-file includes via an autoloader-function (IS THIS MAYBE THE PROBLEM???)

Comment: do you want to have a constant in your class?

Comment: Where's code with usage of constant?

Comment: Maybe - I just need to make the constant useable everywhere after it's defined.. :)

Comment: Alma Do: The usage is in the "$dispatch = new $controllerName();"'s parent class :)

Comment: Can you show the code where you're trying to access these constants?

Comment: Your constants are defined after the class include?

Comment: 2 seconds, I can try to explain, what I'm doing :)

Comment: I've tried to explain the logic of the router :)